get a message in logs "DrainMode mode enabled" and the durable function suddenly stops in the middle
In a middle of running a function, I get a message in logs "DrainMode mode enabled" and the function suddenly stops in the middle.
How can I prevent this, so that at least already running functions get finished?
Googling around, it seems this is meant to run for automatic scaling, with the idea that if the load is low it will stop some instance of the function app. However, it's completely stopping it all for me.

Please check the below provided solution.

Drain Mode is a feature of the Azure Functions with Consumption and Premium plans to enable graceful scale-in of workers with minimal impact on executing function invocations.

Azure Functions uses Scale Controller which decides the scaling behavior and monitor the rate of events.

Drain mode in Azure Functions is designed for a graceful shutdown of the function host up to Functions timeout periods by completing the inflight invocations and stops listening for new events from triggering sources.

Drain mode comes into picture where a worker was signaled to shut down but continues to process new events or when the scale controller decides to scale down a worker.


When it sends a request to the Admin API to enter drain mode, the host will Stop listening for new requests and all the executing Functions on that instance will receive a cancellation token which can be handled further.
Code to handle cancellation token in Azure functions:
try
  { 
  foreach (var message in messages)
     {
         if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                log.LogInformation("A cancellation token was received. Taking precautionary actions.");
                log.LogInformation("Precautionary activities --complete--.");
                break;
            }
         else
            {
                //logic
                log.LogInformation($"Message: {message} was processed.");
            }
         }
  }
catch (Exception ex)
  {
   log.LogInformation($"Something unexpected happened: {ex.Message}");
  }

The Azure Function listeners would be stopped as well when all the currently executing invocations have stopped and ensures that the worker is shutting down and doesn’t handle any new invocations.
In case of premium plan, the function app instances will be dynamically added and removed based on load of incoming requests.
References:
DrainMode mode enabled
